# concat the multiple columns values of row in a string and remove the space using Javascript

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Am getting the row text using getText in a variable and using replace method, removing the spaces after the text of each column output.

```
    var getRowText = await $(`(//`tbody[@class='data-tablecontent'])[3]/tr[${i}]`).getText();  
    console.log(getRowText.replace(/ \s+/g, ''));
```

But am getting output as below:

```
 +columnOneValue
    +columnTwoValue
    +columnThreeValue
```

Instead am expecting output as below

```
**columnOneValue columnTwoValue columnThreeValue**
```

Can someone help how do I get output as a single string instead of separate line

Comment: You have unbalanced backticks in your template literal.

Comment: Please show the value of `getRowText`. The fact that you get it using `getText()` is irrelevant.

Comment: This is how am getting the value of getRowText which is coming as correct.What I don't want is the white spacing after the column values.               
[0-0] columnOneValue                                                                                                                      [0-0] columnTwoValue

Comment: Your output has newlines between the values. Your regexp starts with space, so it won't match the newline before the whitespace.

Comment: in the future I'd recommend using https://regex101.com/ to test out your regular expressions on your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space at the beginning of the regexp, it prevents matching a sequence of whitespace that begins with newline. Get rid of it.

And since you want a single space between each value in the result, the replacement should be a space, not an empty string.

```js
let getRowText = `columnOneValue
   columnTwoValue
   columnThreeValue`;

console.log(getRowText.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please answer if I don't want space in between the column values and output should be as : columnOneValuecolumnTwoValuecolumnThreeValue @Barmar

Comment: Then use an empty string instead of a space, like in your original code.

Comment: But it is concating every word of the column value .For ex  output should be columnOneValue.columnTwoValue letter word  columnThreeValue.                                                                                                                   spacing between letter and word should not be removed

Comment: Isn't that what you want? It removes all spaces.

Comment: Can you get each column separately, instead of as a single string? Then you can put them in an array and use `join()`.